# Opening different WebStorm projects with batch file

Tags: batch-file, webstorm

I wrote a batch file that starts webstorm and starts other things too. I will just copy the relevant part here:

```
start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 8.0.4\bin" WebStorm.exe
```

This works great, and was good when I had only just one project. And since WebStorm doesn't support opening multiple projects it start always with opening the last one that I was working on.

But, and here is my question:

How can I write a batch file that opens webstorm with specified project?

For example:

```
start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 8.0.4\bin" WebStorm.exe  [[D:\Projects\A project]]
```

then in another script file I will write:

```
start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 8.0.4\bin" WebStorm.exe  [[D:\Projects\B project]]
```

Thank you for your answer in advance!

Patry0t

Comment: If you start WebStorm with path to the desired folder as a parameter (e.g. `webstorm C:\projects\supersite.com`) then it will either open existing project (will check if `.idea` subfolder (project settings) is present) or will create new one for that folder. So yes -- you are moving in right direction. P.S. I do not think that you need .bat file for that -- just add path to webstrom folder into your `PATH` environment and DOS will be able to find it there.

Comment: allright, I will try this one tomorrow, thanks LazyOne

Comment: how can I give you the points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start WebStorm with path to the desired folder as a parameter (e.g. `webstorm C:\projects\supersite.com`) then it will:

- either open existing project (IDE will check if `.idea` subfolder (project settings) is present)
- or will create new project for that folder.

So yes -- you are moving in right direction.

**P.S.**
I do not see why would you need `.bat` file for that -- add path to WebStrom folder into your `PATH` environment variable and Windows/DOS will be able to find it there (so there will be no need to use full path to `webstorm.exe` file).